# Validation Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a hard time in this one.  I want to add data to a column in my database.

If there is an existing type in the database, then it not going to add, and if not it is going to add.  However, it seems that my `$validate` is always empty.

Thanks in Advance. I really Appreciate your Help Thanks again.

this my add_item_type.php

```
$newi = $_GET["newi"];
$dept = $_GET["dept"];

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fumc");

$sql = mysqli_query($connection," SELECT * FROM items WHERE type = '".$newi."' ");

while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$validate = $data['department'];
}

if($validate=="")
{

}
else
{
mysqli_query($connection," INSERT INTO items (type,department)VALUES('".$newi."','".$dept."') "); 
echo mysqli_affected_rows($connection);
}    

?>
```

My database name is fumc, my table name is items and inside my table i have type And Department .... One of my type is keyboard and department is IT..

this is my main.php

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="fumc.png">
    <link href="css123/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css123/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<input type="button" name="modal" value="Add Item Type" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:100px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
<center>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style='top:0px;'>
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content" style="width:400px;">
<div class="modal-header " style='background:#ddd;'>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-family:Arial Black;color:green;"><center><b>ADD ITEM TYPE</b></center></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <br>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $department?>'name ='dept' id='dept'>
    <center>
        <font class='text-success' ><b>NEW ITEM TYPE</b>
        <input type='text' name ='newi' id='newi'  style='margin-left:10px;border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;background:Transparent;'>
        </font>
    </center>                   
</div>
<br>            
<div class="modal-footer" style='background:#ddd;'>
</form> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info " name="add" id="add" >Add Item Type</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</center>

<script>            
$(function(dd){
$("#modal").on("click",function(dd){

var dept = $("#dept").val();      
var newi = $("#newi").val();      

});

$("#add").on("click",function(tt){

var dept = $("#dept").val();
var newi = $("#newi").val();      

$.get("add_item_type.php?newi="+newi+"&dept="+dept,function(values){
    location.reload();             
});

});

});
</script>

<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Need help Please..! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use MySQL's built in `UNIQUE` attribute. Set the department column of your database table to be unique, then you can use a query like this:

`"INSERT IGNORE INTO items (type,department) VALUES ('".$newi."','".$dept."')"`

This query will only insert a new row if the `$dept` value doesn't match any of the other values in the department column.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!